# Undefined control sequence, title, math and newcommand

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, titles, music

Deal all,

I have the following couple of new commands, using amsmath and relsize packages :

```
\newcommand*{\chiffraged}[2]{$\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\mathlarger{#1}}{\mathlarger{#2}}$}
\newcommand*{\sixcinqbarre}{\chiffraged{6}{\cancel{5}}}
```

which allow me to display, in a regular text, a musical chord notation like this (chord C) : 
[image]

When I use my `\sixcinqbarre` in my text, no problem, everyting works (example in french, sorry):

```
     On trouvera tout naturellement l'écriture \textit{do ré}\quartesixte~\textit{mi}6
précédée du \textit{si}\sixcinqbarre .
     L'accord de passage est en général faible tandis que les deux accords de tonique sont
    placés sur les temps forts.
    L'accord sur la sensible est ainsi lui aussi en position faible. On a
    donc \textit{si do ré mi}. Nous en donnons un exemple.
```

gives:

[image]

When I use it in a title with no toc reference, like `\subsection*{\sixcinqbarre}`, idem, no problem. But when I use it in a regular title, like this `\subsection{\sixcinqbarre}`, I have the following error :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\rs@makelargerchoice ...displaystyle \rs@mathatom
\m@th $}}{\displaystyle \l...
l.197 ...\sixcinqbarre ~avec la basse descendante}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Edit: After some tests, it seems that the use of the hyperref package is the cause of the error. Here is a code to test:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\chiffraged}[2]{$\protect\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\protect\mathlarger{#1}}{\protect\mathlarger{#2}}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sixcinqbarre}{\chiffraged{6}{\cancel{5}}}

\begin{document}
\section{\sixcinqbarre}
\end{document}
```

Comment the `\usepackage[]{hyperref}`, and it works! However I would like to keep it...any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should do `\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sixcinqbarre}{\chiffraged{6}{\cancel{5}}}` and similarly for `\chiffraged`, if you plan to use the macros in a moving argument (sectional title or caption).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) And sorry for the possible duplication...
I tried what you suggested : to replace `\newcommand*` by `\DeclareRobustCommand*` in both commands, I still have the same error...idem if I replace `\sixcinqbarre` by `\protect\sixcinqbarre` in the title. Idem if I do both.
Did I miss something? Maybe a package inclusion ?

Comment: Up, does anyone can help me on this one?

Comment: Please, edit your question adding a minimal example of code producing the issue. The question might be reopened, if a quick workaround cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I added a bunch of code to test, with a new hint on the cause of the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `hyperref` requires another level of protection:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark} % recommended

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\chiffraged}[2]{%
  $\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\mathlarger{#1}}{\mathlarger{#2}}$%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sixcinqbarre}{\chiffraged{6}{\cancel{5}}}
% also protect the commands for the bookmarks
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  % provide an approximate representation for the bookmarks
  \renewcommand\chiffraged[2]{#1 #2}%
  \renewcommand\sixcinqbarre{6/5}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{\sixcinqbarre{} \chiffraged{6}{4}}

\end{document}
```

You may consider a different definition for `\chiffraged`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\chiffraged}[2]{%
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\\[1pt]#2\end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Now it works like a charm.
Why do you recommand to change `\chiffraged` ?

Comment: @jules Well, I think that a generalized fraction is not the right tool. You might use a display style fraction, instead of using `\mathlarger`, though.

Comment: Yes I understand, I'll follow your advice!

Answer (score 2):

Special symbols are not allowed in pdf bookmarks. As hyperref generates these names from the section titles, you have to provide an alternative text `\section{\texorpdfstring{\sixcinqbarre}{Bla}}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\chiffraged}[2]{$\protect\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\protect\mathlarger{#1}}{\protect\mathlarger{#2}}$}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sixcinqbarre}{\chiffraged{6}{\cancel{5}}}

\begin{document}
\section{\texorpdfstring{\sixcinqbarre}{Bla}}
\end{document}
```

[image]